# Where am I wrong Codingbat Python exercise?

Tags: python

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers.

```
def sum67(nums):
  for i in range(len(nums)):
   if nums[i] == 6:
  nums[i] = 0
  for j in range(len(nums)): 
    if nums[j] == 7:
      nums[j] =0
      nums[i:j+1] = 0
  return sum(nums)
```

Comment: Awesome problem, what's your question? Where are you having issues in your code?

Comment: I'm getting an error  "can only assign an iterable"

Comment: It's true: `nums[i:j+1] = 0` You can only assign an iterable to a list slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sum67(nums):
    result = 0
    skip = False
    for num in nums:
        if not skip:
            if num == 6:
                skip = True
            else:
                result += num
        elif skip and num == 7:
            skip = False
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert sum67([1, 2, 2]) == 5
    assert sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]) == 5
    assert sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2]) == 4
    assert sum67([1, 6, 2, 2, 7, 1, 6, 99, 99, 7]) == 2
    assert sum67([1, 6, 2, 6, 2, 7, 1, 6, 99, 99, 7]) == 2
    assert sum67([2, 7, 6, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7]) == 18
    assert sum67([2, 7, 6, 2, 6, 2, 7]) == 9
    assert sum67([1, 6, 7, 7]) == 8
    assert sum67([6, 7, 1, 6, 7, 7]) == 8
    assert sum67([6, 8, 1, 6, 7]) == 0
    assert sum67([]) == 0
    assert sum67([6, 7, 11]) == 11
    assert sum67([11, 6, 7, 11]) == 22
    assert sum67([2, 2, 6, 7, 7]) == 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started learning programming. and here is how I solved the question you shared.

```
def sum67(nums):
    sum = 0
    pos6 = []
    pos7 = []

    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(nums) == 1:
        return nums[0]
    else:
        # first identifying the positions of 6s and 7s in the array "nums"
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] == 6:
                pos6 = pos6 + [i]

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] == 7:
                pos7 = pos7 + [i]

        # ignoring the 7s that appears before the 1st 6 (To be added to final sum)
        if len(pos6) > 0:
            for i in range(len(pos7)):
                if pos6[0] > pos7[0]:
                    pos7 = pos7[1:]

            # ignoring the 7s that are not pairable with any 6
            if len(pos7) > len(pos6):
                pos7 = pos7[:len(pos6)]

            # replacing every digit between 6 and 7 (including 6 & 7) with 0
            for i in range(len(pos6)):
                var1 = 0
                while var1 <= (pos7[i]-pos6[i]):
                    nums[pos6[i] + var1] = 0
                    var1 += 1

        # adding all the values within the array
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            sum = sum + nums[i]

        return sum
```